# Identfier Declared Errors

Tags: c

when i try using scanf in C at Visual Studio 2012 ultimate. "the character cant be declared" errors are given by compiler.

```
int i;
scanf("%d",&i);//identifier declareded "i"
```

otherwise there is no error

```
int i=13;
printf("%d",i);//13
```

Comment: greats from me! but why?

Comment: Questions such as this should contain a [self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

`scanf("%d",&d);` to `scanf("%d",&i);` will solve the problem.

Comment: sorry there is a mistake when i wrote here. correct state is now seen.

Comment: Errors is stil given by compiler